# Do or Does - help please

Tags: word-usage

If you or your attorney do not call me by 5:00 p.m. today, then I will go ahead and file a complaint.

Do v. Does

'Do" sounds best, but why?  Which is correct to use:  do or does?

Answer (score 2):

Does.
Here's reference: Look at this document from Purdue University's writing lab. https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/599/01/

Point 3 clearly states that the verb should take the form of the nearest subject. (Attorney)
Also, since both are singular joined by 'or' there will be no plural form of the verb.
If this were 'and' it would be plural (do).

Comment: I would be careful taking rules of thumb as somehow absolute law, especially when the source manages to spend a lot of confusing text on explaining the difference between _don't_ and _doesn't_, claiming the latter is used for the singular, except the first and second person. They seem to just _love_ making rules complicated and thus more like texts of law...

Comment: Thanks for doubting the source. I found another document from Yale resources here. http://www.yale.edu/graduateschool/writing/forms/Subject%20and%20Verb%20Agreement.pdf   . (The points 10,11,12  verify  the subject verb agreement I cited above. ) P.S. Also, MW defines grammar as ' the set of rules that explain how words are used in a language'. So I guess we have to comply with it at some point, if we want to be correct.

Comment: Comply with a description? You may find there are those that strongly disagree :) As to the new source: either/or emphasizes the singular and ensures that not _both_ subjects perform the action. The usage is open to debate, I doubt there are very clear rules - at least not simple ones :)

Comment: I welcome rebuttal if you have a source that disproves the rule.

Comment: I admit I find it a bit hard to search on usage of a common word like _or_, and find useful results, but "you, the next online guy or his friend do not make a trend" is a counterexample of your quoted rule from actual usage. The [source](http://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/31244144) is admittedly not linguistic. If I find some time I will see if I can find some more respectable sources of usage that contradicts rules :)

Comment: Here's a citation from the Oxford Dictionary of American Usage and Style: about the general rule of subject-verb agreement: "The simple rule is to use a plural verb with a plural subject, a singular verb with a singular subject. But there are complications. If a sentence has two or more singular subjects connected by and, use a plural verb. Yet if the subjects refer to the same person or thing, use a singular verb . And if the sentence has two singular subjects connected by or, either … or, or neither … nor, use a singular verb. See either (C) & neither … nor (A)."...

Comment: Also read into the 'proximity concord'. Luckily for me I work on a university campus.Here's what Oxford Companion to English Language has: "In such cases, proximity concord operates, the verb agreeing with the nearest noun. It can also operate in awkward constructions like *Neither my sister nor I am going and occurs in the traditional use of a singular verb after More than one, where both grammar and meaning require a plural verb: More than one person has remarked on this strange fact."

Answer (score 1):

Do.  I agree.  Why?  Perhaps because a call from your attorney would be understood as in effect coming from you, since the attorney represents your interest, so "you" dominates in the disjunction.  We could think of "or your attorney" as being a parenthetical addition.

Comment: Your answer goes against a very specific grammatical rule, as mentioned by other commenters. Do you have a source for your reasons for breaking this well-established rule? The way I understand it, the very reason for this grammatical rule is cases like this.

Comment: You should try to keep facts apart from theories.  It's a fact that "do" here sounds better to at least two English speakers, the OP and me.  You cite a prescriptive rule to the contrary, but why do you think the rule is right?  It's just something someone made up!  (In **The Syntactic Phenomena of English**, McCawley discusses this old prescriptive rule and finds it without foundation.)

Comment: Aaaargh. I, a native speaker, disagree completely! :((( Does sounds better to my BE ear ...